# Google Apps Script Trigger Issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I am currently working with Google Apps Scripts in my project. But Facing issue with triggers.
Scenario :

Two User 
- UserA
- UserB

Logged in as UserA, created a google Spreadsheet and script to it. Also created few triggers. For e.g.

[Trigger Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6E1bD.png)

The Spreadsheet is shared to UserB with edit access. Now I am logged in as UserB.

Case 1: Trying to add a new trigger to the script 
Result => Trigger is created but only visible to UserB

Case 2: Modifying the existing trigger (created by UserA)
Result => Cannot see the trigger created by UserA. Even if modify opreration happens without any error. no changes are applied to that trigger.

Case 3: Deleting the existing trigger (created by UserA)
Result => Cannot see the trigger created by UserA. Even if Delete opreration happens without any error. no changes are applied to that trigger. I can still see it with UseA login.

My Qusetion:

1.Is there any way to 
   -Modify the triggers by UserB which are created by UserA ?
   -Add a new trigger by UserB and is visible to UserA?

2. Do Google apps script has any feature to change the context/session? for example, though UserB is logged in;changing the session to UserA and performing the whole operations(Add/Modify/Delete) and then again changing back to UseB session?

Below are my methods:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("assignEditUrls")
     .timeBased()
     .atHour(0)
     .nearMinute(59)
     .everyDays(1)
     .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('processInputXML')
     .timeBased()
     .everyMinutes(5)
     .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('assignFormResponseIDs')
     .timeBased()
     .everyMinutes(30)
     .create();

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('setSRHistoryColumn')
     .timeBased()
     .everyMinutes(1)
     .create();

}


    function createSpreadSheetTriggers() {
       var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

        ScriptApp.newTrigger("onOpen")
       .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
       .onOpen()
       .create();

       ScriptApp.newTrigger("sendEmailNotificationsOnFormSubmit")
       .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
       .onFormSubmit()
       .create();

       ScriptApp.newTrigger("notifyProductAssigneeOnFormSubmit")
       .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
       .onFormSubmit()
       .create();
    }


    function deleteTrigger() {
      // Loop over all triggers.
      var allTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();  
      for (var i = 0; i < allTriggers.length; i++) {
          ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(allTriggers[i]);
      }
    }
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access the manual triggers which were created by others who have edited access to spreadsheet or google app script.

[From Google App script documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/collaborating#collaborating_and_triggers)

> When you collaborate on a project, any installable triggers that you
>   create are not shared with those who have access to your project. If
>   you need to have a consistent trigger setup for all collaborators, you
>   can use the Script service to create triggers programmatically, at run
>   time.

As mentioned in the documentation you can programmatically schedule the triggers.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. I added triggers programmatically by UserA, but still not able to access and modify those by UserB.